# C# private properties - are they used/make sense?

Tags: c#, properties, private

I'm starting out as a C# enthusiast and it seems to me that properties should always be public. Private property wouldn't make sense. Would it?

Would this:

```
private string propertyOne {get; set;}
```

be equivalent to this:

```
public string propertyOne {private get; private set;}
```

Comment: Yes those are equivalent. If you were writing a class for someone else to use there may be things in your file you do not want them to have access to. For example maybe someone would want to get an interest rate but you would not want them to be able to change the value of the rate. In this case you could do public double rate{ get; private set;}

Comment: Just a note: The .NET Design Guidelines for Library developers specify that properties should be Pascal Cased. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The up to date link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx. The posted link is from .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, private properties can make sense, particularly in cases where you have logic you want to implement in the getters/setters. You may only want these accessible within the class (hence they're private) but you still want to encapsulate the getter/setter logic in one place.

There is a difference between the two lines of code you printed. Someone reflecting over public properties won't see the first one but they will see the second, even if they can't invoke the getter/setter.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of using a Property is to encapsulate rather than just present a raw variable to the 'outside world'. That way you can also have an extra logic in your accessors.

So No, a purely private property wouldn't be the usual use case.

It's not uncommon to see public properties with a private setter though.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, yes the latter would equal the former in functionality but would make no sense to implement it as such.

I tend to use

```
public string propertyOne {get; private  set;}
```

As sometimes I want it publicly available but only the class it exists in able to set the value. But mostly its also when you want to encapsulate other logic into the getters an setters to perform other functions.

But more often than not they are public properties, to encapsulate other functionality.

Comment: your example propertyOne is world-settable but only privately readable. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those two bits of code are equivalent.  I've never created a private property with an auto getter/setter.  Doesn't seem very useful.  I have used private properties with an actual implementation for the getter.  A private get method (or property getter) can be useful.